# Chromosomes in humans and chimpanzees

Tags: human-biology

I am reading a book titled 'Critical Thinking Skills for Dummies' by Martin Cohen, in which I came across this passage:
'Although humans share 98 per cent of their genes with chimpanzees, they share precisely 0 per cent of their chromosomes -and chromosomes are what actually do things.'
Is this correct?

- List item

Comment: If he did, that's a really dumb thing to say, and there is an extreme lack of critical thinking present in that statement. Chromosomes are a bit like houses, houses where genes live. Genes are "what do things"; chromosomes themselves are inactive. [Here](https://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/permanent/human-origins/understanding-our-past/dna-comparing-humans-and-chimps) you can see an example of a human and a chimpanzee chromosome, and an brief explanation of chromosomes and genes.

Comment: @anongoodnurse that (that chrs are inactive) is an odd statement. Chromosomes and genes are not distinct things, genes are DNA sequences, and chromosomes are large stretches of DNA sequence. Genes _are_ chromosomes in the sense that my arms _are_ me. So no, chromosomes are not inactive. Perhaps a closer analogy would be that chromosomes are books that contain many sentences. Some of the sentences are nonsense, and some carry meaning (genes). Yes, it is the ones that carry meaning that "do things" but the book isn't inactive as it is made up of the bits that carry meaning and those that don't.

Comment: Minor nitpicking aside, I have to agree with anongoodnurse's sentiment: that sentence is nonsensical. I don't understand how the author decides to quantify whether or not chromosomes are "shared". Is that in terms of sequence? Gene complement per chromosome? Order of the genes? Can you clarify what the specific claim you are asking about it? The statement as a whole is neither true nor false because it is nonsensical. Is there some context to clarify?

Comment: @terdon - Your analogy is better, true. Chromosomes are "inactive" in so far as switching to your analogy) the book is closed. You can't read a closed book; it must be opened in order to have phrases read and meanings understood. So, too, must the chromosome be "opened" to let the genes out. The book houses (and contains) the words. Chromosomes house (and contain) the genes. But yours is the better analogy. Regardless, we are both aware of the stupidity of that statement alone. It may be explained further, but I couldn't locate it with searxching.

Comment: Perhaps the author is suggesting you should critically think to ignore his book.

Comment: This might be an exercise in logical fallacies and arguments. I wish we had the exact wording so that the context could be read. All we have is a paraphrase. The author doesn't seem to be an idiot, although he appears to deny climate change as an argument from authority...

Comment: @anongoodnurse or terdon (sorry only 1 tag allowed), I do think it would be helpful if one of you could write an answer, since this is a good faith question and there is a clear answer. Then that could settle it. No one seems to be of the opinion that this is a homework-style question, if only due to the incredulity that we collectively feel towards what this Cohen character is saying.

Comment: @terdon see above

Comment: @MaximilianPress I can't answer since I don't understand the question. If the question is "is it actually chromosomes that 'do things'?" then it isn't even answerable since that is a nonsensical question. If it is "do humans and chimps share their chromosomes", then we would need an explanation of what is meant by "shared" in this context. In its current state, the question is too unclear to be answerable.